# SSD performance on Ubuntu + Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, performance, ubuntu-14.04, ssd

I'm trying to improve the performance of server for nginx 100TB/month images distributions. But I have two problems: high CPU load and periodical splashes (I don't know why)

Hardware is quite poor (this is the challenge, 100Tb on sub-standard hardware):

- AMD Opteron X2150 APU, 4 cores 1.1GHz
- SATA-SSD 256 GB  ZTC-SM201-256G
- 8 GB RAM
- Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe

Ubuntu 14.04

Nginx 1.12.2

Content: images with 250k-2M size. around 200Gb. Seldom write.

**Nginx cache config:**

> proxy_cache_path /home/XXX levels=1:2 keys_zone=manga:90m max_size=230G inactive=15d;

**fstab:**

> UUID=34d74174-f584-42aa-b838-57b37b89007a /               ext2   errors=remount-ro 0       1
>
> UUID=c033e0f8-5034-4076-9aad-f238bbbecedf /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
>
> UUID=1e5cd397-e881-4075-8b21-9c8e62fa6045 /home           ext2
>    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,discard        0       2
>
> UUID=693c70c7-4f09-4c2f-8ba1-c6c4de7c1b70 none            swap    sw   0       0

**/etc/sysctl.conf**

> vm.swappiness=0 
>   vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50

In atop I see nginx on top

[image] 
[image]
[image]

What reason of splashes???

- I have checked crontab -- nothing
- No access logs in nginx
- Enough memory, 717Mb free
- FS journal has been disabled
- Nginx cache not full. ~25% free

Any ideas, how to improve performance?

Will it help if I:

- Install ubuntu 16.04
- Upgrade cpu from 1.1GHz to 1.5GHz
- ???

Thx!

**UPDATE**

I have seen **kswapd0** in atop top. But I have set **vm.swappiness=0** and reload conf two days ago.

I'm also interested in where the hardware bottleneck is, CPU, SSD or Ethernet

Comment: Do you have an actual problem or have you just arbitrarily decided "these numbers are too high"? You have low-end hardware that is seeing some load, but nothing indicates it is actually overloaded. The spikes can come from whatever, cron jobs, traffic spikes, solar flares - *you* need to know what's running on your machine that could create these spikes.

Comment: @Sven during splashes nginx sometimes stops serving requests for 5-20sec. Also, I can't wring 60Mbytes/sec from the server. I checked cron, I have same traffic on another servers (different hardware and locations), but see spikes only on the one server. Yes. I know, the hardware is low-end. It simple to have 10Gbps with $10000 budget =)

Comment: Can you try to capture more detailed metrics during those splashes / spikes? An obvious mitigation here is to use a content distribution network to reduce load on the server, but that might cost more than the low end server.